# Sunspot Solr Search - How to filter with multiple 'with'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have the following SOLR search where I am trying to find a few places in my database based on lat/lng using Geohashes and making sure that the places have an affiliate link through an `Affiliates` table.

```
search = Sunspot.search(opts[:types]) do
  any_of do
    0.upto(opts[:range]) do
      geohash = GeoHash.encode(place.lat, place.lng, precision)
      neighbors = GeoHash.neighbors(geohash) rescue []
      geohashes = [geohash] + neighbors
      with(:affiliate_names, ['company_a', 'company_b']) 
      with(:"geohash_#{precision}", geohashes)
      precision -= 1
    end
  end
  without(:class, IgnoreClass) unless opts[:types].include?(VacationRental)
end
search.hits
```

The issue I am running into is that this search pulls in both places within the geohash and places with the affiliate_names 'company_a' and 'company_b'. Specifically, these two lines:

```
      with(:affiliate_names, ['company_a', 'company_b'])
      with(:"geohash_#{precision}", geohashes)
```

I want the places to be filtered by geohash AND affiliate_name. Right now, the two with statements act like an OR.

How do I do a Solr Sunspot search to pull in records that fulfill both the with criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can nest the code as follows

```
all_of
  with(:affiliate_names, ['company_a', 'company_b'])
  with(:"geohash_#{precision}", geohashes)
end
```

This will ensure that the solr record that you query fits both the requirement.